# What does the phrase "stay closer to home" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Here is a sentence from a game advertisement text:

> Whether you’re looking to escape on holiday or **are staying closer to
>   home**, these fun games will certainly send you on a long adventure
>   ride.

I am not sure if staying means **to be at home** or **be near home** here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which game? please link to the source. I suspect that this would be read differently in the USA and the UK.

Comment: @JamesK Unfortunately, I cannot share the source due to confidentiality reasons. The text addresses the US audience.

Comment: If this is for a US audience, going "on holiday" has a particularly British/European or Upper-Class sense to it... I would recommend using "on vacation".

Comment: I'd be more concerned with the awkward *a long adventure ride*. Both *a long adventure*  and *a long ride* are fine (the first is more appropriate), but not the combination of the two.

Answer (score 1):

"Staying closer to home" is simply what you do when *not* going away for a  holiday/vacation, but still taking the time off from school/work. It does not imply that the person is at home the whole time, or even in their neighborhood the whole time.

It is an extremely relative term and can change meaning based on the context:

- A mom saying "stay close to home" to her children that are bicycling, probably means to not go more than two streets away (or something similar)
- A mom saying "stay close to home" to her son who has just graduated college, probably means stay in the same metropolitan area (or even the same state).